# I want each result to have its own unique URL

Tags: php, json

**I want each result to have its own unique URL like this:**

> https:/MySite.com/file_code/Interesting-video-title
>   https:/MySite.com/file_code/Interesting-video-title

**It's possible ?**
My goal is that every result can appear on google!
"ps: I'm a very beginner in the code"

```
   <?php
   error_reporting(0);

   $json = '{ "message": "OK",
       "result": {
           "files": [
               {
                   "code": "FILE_CODE",
                   "id": "FILE_ID",
                   "name": "Interesting video title",
                   "size": "215.7 MB",
                   "uploaded": "2019-11-07"
               },
               {
                   "code": "FILE_CODE",
                   "id": "FILE_ID",
                   "name": "Interesting video title",
                   "size": "215.7 MB",
                   "uploaded": "2019-11-07"
               }
           ],
           "pagination": {
               "current_page": 1,
               "first_page": 1,
               "last_page": 1,
               "next_page": "",
               "previous_page": "",
               "total": 2
           },
           "total": 2
       },
       "success": 1
   }';

   $data_arrays = json_decode($json, true);


   foreach($data_arrays as $data){
       foreach($data['files'] as $result){

           echo "CODE: ".$result['code']."\n";
           echo "ID: ".$result['id']."\n";
           echo "NAME: ".$result['name']."\n";
           echo "SIZE: ".$result['size']."\n";
           echo "UPLOADED: ".$result['uploaded']."\n";
           echo "----------\n";
           #if($results){
           #    echo "<pre>";
           #    print_r($results);
           #}


       }
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Certainly. The concept is this: all requests are routed (by server) to index.php by using url rewriting.  For example, mySite.com/1234/some%20title would be routed to index.php which would grab the request_uri, dissect it into variables (1234, etc and )and show the corresponding view.  Research url rewriting, search engine friendly urls, mvc. Try it out, then ask another question if you need  to

Comment: Welcome! You are telling us what you are expecting, but your code makes no attempt to specifically solve it. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to attempt the task before you can have an issue with it requiring help. It may just be a simple case of use. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask